# Translation of VBA script to Apps Script (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to create a google sheet that applies the same commands from excel but I'm not sure if this script would work on App Script of Google Sheets.

This is the code that I used for Microsoft excel.
[image: VBA Script]

Basically, creating a summary sheet of the original using drop down option.